# SwiftUI - Position a rectangle relative to another view in ZStack

Tags: swift, swiftui

**The task**

I am creating a bar chart with SwiftUI and I am looking for the best approach to position the average indicator, the horizontal yellow line, shown in the picture below:

[image]

**The goal**

I need to be able to position the yellow line (rectangle with 1 point in height) relative to the bars (also rectangles) of the chart. For simplicity let us imagine that the tallest possible bar is 100 points and the average is 75. My goal is to draw the yellow line exactly 75 points above the bottom of the bars.

**The problem**

In my example I am placing the line on top of the chart using a ZStack. I can position the line vertically using a GeometryReader, however I do not know how to position it in reference to the bottom of the bars.

Here my playground code:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct BarChart: View {
    var measurements : [Int]
    var pastColor: Color
    var todayColor: Color
    var futureColor: Color

    let labelsColor = Color(UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 1.0))

    func monthAbbreviationFromInt(_ day: Int) -> String {
        let da = Calendar.current.shortWeekdaySymbols
        return da[day]
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {

            VStack {

                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.yellow)
                        .frame(width: 12, height: 2, alignment: .center)

                    Text("Desired level")
                        .font(.custom("Helvetica", size: 10.0))
                        .foregroundColor(labelsColor)
                }
                .padding(.bottom , 50.0)

                HStack {

                    ForEach(0..<7) { day in

                        VStack {

                            Spacer()

                            Text(String(self.measurements[day]))
                                .frame(width: CGFloat(40), height: CGFloat(20))
                                .font(.footnote)
                                .lineLimit(1)
                                .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                                .foregroundColor(self.labelsColor)

                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(day > 0 ? self.futureColor : self.pastColor)
                                .frame(width: 20, height: CGFloat(self.measurements[day]*2))
                                .transition(.slide)
                                .cornerRadius(3.0)

                            Text("\(self.monthAbbreviationFromInt(day))\n\(day)")
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                .font(.footnote)
                                .frame(height: 20)
                                .lineLimit(2)
                                .minimumScaleFactor(0.2)
                                .foregroundColor(self.labelsColor)

                        }
                        .frame(height: 200, alignment: .bottom )
                    }

                }
            }
            .padding()

            VStack {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    //Yellow line
                    Rectangle()
                        .path(in: CGRect(x: 0,
                                     y: 350, //This is now a random value, but I should detect and use the bottom coordinate of the bars to place the line at exactly 75 points above that coordinate
                        width: geometry.size.width,
                        height: 1))
                        .fill(Color.yellow)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the relative position of the bottom of the bars so that I can place the line correctly?

Is there another approach you would suggest?

Thank you in advance

Comment: if you already create all the bars and labels, you know how to create this yellow rectangle as well.

Comment: Show us your SwiftUI logic; to suggest something from just a screenshot is dicey.

Comment: @staticVoidMan added my playground code

Comment: OK, I didn't see you own code before submitting my answer. I am sure you are able to adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

example

```
import SwiftUI

struct Data: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let value: CGFloat
    let color: Color
}
struct ContentView: View {
    let data = [Data(value: 35, color: .red),
                  Data(value: 100, color: .green),
                  Data(value: 70, color: .yellow),
                  Data(value: 25, color: .blue),
                  Data(value: 55, color: .orange)]

    var maxValue: CGFloat {
        data.map { (element) -> CGFloat in
            element.value
        }.max() ?? 1.0
    }
    var average: CGFloat {
        guard !data.isEmpty else { return 0 }
        let sum = data.reduce(into: CGFloat.zero) { (res, data) in
            res += data.value
        }
        return sum / CGFloat(data.count)
    }
    var body: some View {

        HStack {
            ForEach(data) { (bar) in
                Bar(t: bar.value / self.maxValue, color: bar.color, width: 20)
            }
        }
        .background(Color.pink.opacity(0.1))
        .overlay(
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Color.primary.frame(height: 1).position(x: proxy.size.width / 2, y: proxy.size.height * ( 1 - self.average / self.maxValue))
            }
        ).padding(.vertical, 100).padding(.horizontal, 20)

    }
}

struct Bar: View {
    let t: CGFloat
    let color: Color
    let width: CGFloat

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Path { (path) in
                path.move(to: .init(x: proxy.size.width / 2, y: proxy.size.height))
                path.addLine(to: .init(x: proxy.size.width / 2, y: 0))
                }
            .trim(from: 0, to: self.t)
            .stroke(lineWidth: self.width)
            .foregroundColor(self.color)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

and result
[image]

or slightly adopted to show labels

[image]